# Intertesting problem with UITableViewCell and UITableView, Any solution?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, uitableview

I have a class inherited from `UITableViewController` and this is also the root class. This tableView contains three custom `UITableViewCell`s (loaded from NIB file and not subclassed) and each `UITableViewCell` has one `UITextField`. Now when I implement delegate method

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField
        shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
        replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

I don't recieve any event. This function never gets fired, I tried implementating other delegate methods too but none of them fires. How to fire these delegate methods?

I also want to override `canPerformAction:sender:` function for these `UITextField`s (Which are part of `UITableViewCell`);
How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` method is part of the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol, so you have to set a delegate for these `UITextField`s.

For example, if you were creating the `UITextField`s in your table view contoller code, and assuming the method was implemented in the same contoller, you could do this:

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)];
[textField setDelegate:self];
```

However, you say you're loading the `UITableViewCell`s from XIB files. You have to somehow access the `UITextField`s from inside the code and call the `setDelegate:` method on them. You can do this by using `UIView`'s `subviews` property. For example:

```
UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"foo" bundle:nil];
UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[[controller.view subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Though creating the `UITextField`s in the code is much easier and more elegant, IMHO.

As for overriding the `canPerformAction:sender:` method, you'll have to subclass `UITextField` for that.

Comment: Thanks Can Berk for your tip, it's really helpful. How will i find the index value to pass in objectAtIndex?  Here you are showing passing the value as 0 will it always be 0? As i've 3 controls on tableviewcell, label, textfield and one button. Sorry if it is basic question but i am new to iphone programming.

Comment: It depends on the order in which you add the subviews, but since you're adding the subviews in the XIB file, I guess you'll have to try 0 through 2. As I said, creating the UITableViewCells in code, rather than in Interface Builder, is a better practice. Try to do that if you can, it will be a good exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Is this class a UITextFieldDelegate ? You need to provide more information, source etc....
The fact that you are not getting any event's makes me thing the problem is something missing in the NIB's. I don't use IB or NIB's for anything for this exact reason, debugging problems becomes really hard. Perhaps post your XML's

Comment: RootViewController is delegate of UITextFieldDelegate, I am unable to post my xml file here as it crosses 600 characters. How to upload xml file?